# MySQL structural integrity versus simplicity?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

**My problem:**

- On a `PHP/MySQL` application I have to distinguish the `registered accounts` from the `simple visitors`. Both of them can perform actions which are written into the database. Now I use a separate table for `visitors` and a separate table for `registered accounts.`

**My example solutions so far:**

- **Option #1:** `Registered accounts` and `visitors` are separated into two tables. Both
  of them can have `sessions` and the relationship between the tables are
  `non-mandatory`, since a person is either a `visitor` or a `registered account`.
  [image]

  **Option #2:** Everyone is in one table and the relationship between the tables are mandatory, since everyone can have `sessions`, but since a person is either a `visitor` or a `registered account`, he might not have an `email` or `password`, so that can be NULL. This might lead to errors in the integrity.

[image]

**My question:**

- Should I keep the `accounts` in a separate table from the `visitors` or I
  can put everyone in one table with a BOOLEAN `isThisAccount` variable
  that indicates whenever the person is a `registered account` or just a simple
  `visitor`?

I also am open to different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with a third option: Link sessions to visitors and visitors to accounts. That way you need only one field `visitorID` in the `sessions` table and only one `NULL` column (`accountID` in `visitors`). In my opinion that's conceptually cleaner, since people performing actions are always visitors, who may or may not have an account.